# How to deal with Regular expression in python?

Tags: python

I want to detect this format in my text file "1-321231", I mean any digit, plus '-', plus any digit, 
I wrote this regular expression:

```
\d[-]\d*
```

but I don't know how to use it in python.

Comment: This is the documentation for the `re` module: https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html

Comment: You don't need the character class. `\d-\d+` should be enough.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"Detect" is what we call "Match".
Here is a working example of how to use it:

```
import re
string = '1-321231'
pattern = '\d[-]\d*'
match = re.search(pattern, string)
if match:
    print 'we\'ve got a match!'
```

Answer (score 2):

Like Menyah suggested in a comment, browse the quite comprehensive documentation at https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/re.html

As a quickstart, you can use regular expression like this :

```
import re
text = "I am 1-321231, human-cyborg relations."
list_of_codes = re.findall( "\d[-]\d*", text )
```

Comment: This is _searching_ not _matching_.

Answer (score 2):

you can use [regular expressions](https://docs.python.org/2/howto/regex.html)

```
import re
text =  "1-321231"
pattern = '\d[-]\d*'
match = re.match(pattern , text)
if match:
    print 'Yes'
else:
    print 'No'
```

Answer (score 2):

To start with, try something like:

```
import re

my_text = #grab text from file
my_match = re.search(r'\d[-]\d*', my_text)
print 'Yes' if match else 'No'
```

the `r` before the string ensures that the backslash is not read as an escape character